# How to plot Excel graph of multiple series of data using smooth lines

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office, microsoft-excel-2007

Long time reader, first time questioner. I'm wondering how I'd use the following Excel cell data:
http://screencast.com/t/ZjNkODQ3O

Into a graph which looks like: http://screencast.com/t/MTVhYTY1YTMt

I've been scouting the web and Excel options to no avail.

Any help whatsoever would be greatly appreciated.  I think it is most likely a problem with my table structure.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Into a graph which looks like: http://www.screencast.com/t/MTVhYTY1YTMt

Comment: I was writing an answer and realized that you really need to provide more information. What exactly is being graphed. Be specific what a point on one of those lines represents.

Comment: Your example data shows multiple sheets (10cm, 15cm, etc) Is each sheet the source of Test 1, Test 2, etc in the chart?

Answer (score 1):

You need to draw a scatterplot.